# Replace value of array inside a file

Tags: php

Im testing to replace a value of an specific array inside a file. I only have a problem. Because if it has same values it overrides the only the first. but i want the specific one.

**my file:**

```
<?php

$config = [
  'test1' => 'hello',
  'test2' => 'hello',
  'test3' => 'hello'
];

?>
```

**my function:**

```
public function UpdateConfig($search, $replace)
{
  $file = 'App/Config.php';
  $get  = file_get_contents($file);

  $f = preg_quote($search, '/');
  $r = preg_replace('/' . $f . '/', $replace, $get, 1);

  file_put_contents($file, $r);
}
```

and i use it like this:

```
$this->UpdateConfig($this->config['test2'], 'replaced');
```

The problem is instad of replaceing the value of "test2" it replaced the value of "test1" because it come before "test2". So i want to know how do i replace the value that i specified in the parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: But what is the content of  `$this->config['test2']` ?

Comment: Thats this $config array

Comment: Because you're searching on the __value__ of `test2`, which is identical to the value of `test1`, so how can you expect preg_replace to understand that you're looking for a specific 2nd entry of that value unless you tell it.... you need to modify your search to look for the __key__

Comment: I know, is there a way to tell preg_replace it needs to replace only the value of test2?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are trying to replace on the value, which means that it will alter the first occurence of that given value. Since all your values are the same, the script will alter the first "test1".

The best way would be to actually look up on the "key" of the array,  and then altering the value. This way you makes sure that you always fetch the correct content.

I reworked your script a little, to look like this.

```
class Config 
{
    private $_configPath = 'App/Config.php';
    private $_config = null;

    private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // If config is not already loaded. Load it up
        if( is_null( $this->_config ) || !is_array($this->_config) )
        {
            include($this->_configPath);
            if( isset($config) && is_array($config) )
            {
                $this->_config = $config;
            } else {
                $this->_config = [];
            }
        }
    }

        private function _saveConfig()
        {
            // Export the php-array to a string, and rework the file.
            $string = '<?php $config = ' . var_export( $this->_config, true );
            file_put_contents($this->_configPath, $string);
        }

        public function UpdateConfig($key, $value)
        {
          // Load the configuration
          $this->_loadConfig();

          // Alter the config
          $this->_config[$key] = $value;

          // Save the config
          $this->_saveConfig();
        }


}
```

Which will then be used like this.

```
// Used like this
$config = new Config();
$config->UpdateConfig("test2", "FooBar");
```

Remember to have the proper permissions on the Config.php file, for a write to succeed.

best.
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it one of them is in your file where $config present make $config [GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) in order to get it inside a function so the config file would be

```
my file:
<?php

$GLOBALS['config'] = [
  'test1' => 'hello',
  'test2' => 'hello',
  'test3' => 'hello'
];

?>
```

**AND**

use it like this:

```
$this->UpdateConfig(array_search($GLOBALS['config']['test2'],$GLOBALS['config']), 'replaced');
```

my function:

```
public function UpdateConfig($search, $replace)
{
  foreach ($GLOBALS['config'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key==$search){
      $GLOBALS['config'][$key] = $replace;
    }
  }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($GLOBALS['config']);
```